# Facebook Login with Parse.com iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-login

I am trying to implement Facebook login for my ios app with Parse.com and have had no success yet as there is not much out there about how to implement it with objective c step by step.

So I hope this question will be of help to others also.

In my `app delegate` I have:

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

 [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

now here is where i am not sure what method to put the following code under:

1]for my Facebook login button i created a view in my loginViewController in the storyboard and made that view a FBlogin button. i then connected that view to this IBOutlet

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton;`

then in the loginView.m i have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];

    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"username", @"email", @"password"];    
}
```

with this it logs in the user but nothing more happens it goes back to login screen with the facebook user logged in to facebook.
So I activated the button to be in the view and now I am unsure when to put the code that registers the login.

```
- (void)_loginWithFacebook{ 
    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:@[@"username", @"email", @"password"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            //  NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@ logged in! (%@)",
                                 [PFUser currentUser].username, [PFUser currentUser].objectId];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logged in!"
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

        } else {
            //  NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    }];

}

- (void)saveFacebookUser:(PFUser *)user UserData:(NSDictionary *)userData Picture:(NSString *)pictureUrl Thumbnail:(NSString *)thumbnailUrl
{
    NSString *username = userData[@"username"];
    NSString *email = userData[@"email"];

    user.username = username;
    user.username = [username lowercaseString];
    user.email = email;
    [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error == nil)
         {

         }
         else {

         }
     }];

}
```

Once the user logs in I want to make them go to the rootView and for the facebook user to be a PFUser.CurrentUser and for there username to show

So please help me in logging in the user taking them into the rootView and keeping their username as a parse user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added key-value in Info.plist file ???

Info.plist must looks like:
[image]

This key-value add in you info.plist file by following steps:

1. Go to Project navigation bar (left-side panel)
2. Right click on info.plist file
3. Select "Open As" and click on "Source Code"
4. Place the code between `<dict>` & `</dict>` with the following

> ```
> <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
>   <array>
>       <dict>
>           <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
>           <array>
>               <string>fb+”YOUR Facebook APP ID”</string>
>           </array>
>       </dict>
>   </array>
>   <key>FacebookAppID</key>
>   <string>”YOUR Facebook APP ID”</string>
>   <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
>   <string>Integration using Swift</string>
>   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
>   <array>
>       <string>fbapi</string>
>       <string>fbauth2</string>
>   </array>
>   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
>   <dict>
>       <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
>       <dict>
>           <key>facebook.com</key>
>           <dict>
>               <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
>               <true/>
>               <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
>               <false/>
>           </dict>
>           <key>fbcdn.net</key>
>           <dict>
>               <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
>               <true/>
>               <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
>               <false/>
>           </dict>
>           <key>akamaihd.net</key>
>           <dict>
>               <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
>               <true/>
>               <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
>               <false/>
>           </dict>
>       </dict>
>   </dict>
> ```